# Sprout Forms - Redirect to same page with query string

Tags: plugin-sproutforms

I'm looking to redirect the user to the same page that they were on, with an additional query string.

Is this possible?

Thanks
Adam

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sprout Forms now supports relative redirects.

Example redirect values:

- /thank-you
- thank-you
- ?message=success
- thank-you?message=success
- {siteUrl}
- http://website.com/thank-you

We've also added this info [in the documentation](http://sprout.barrelstrengthdesign.com/craft-plugins/forms/docs/customization/redirects)

Answer (score 2):

Sure, in the control panel for sprout forms you can set the redirect page. Say the url for your contact page is /contact you can do something like redirect to:

```
contact?message=thank-you
```

and then in your contact template do something like:

```
{# Check if we should display a thank you message #}
{% if craft.request.getParam('message') == 'thank-you' %}
 //do stuff here
{% endif %}
```

Sprout installs a bunch of sample forms, there's plenty to gleam and learn from these.

Comment: Thanks for your response, erwinheiser. What if the URL is a specific entry, rather than a contact page where the URL is known? I am using the form on many pages, and would like to redirect to the same page. I envisage that if not possible with Craft Sprout Forms, I may just have to use javascript when the page loads to alter the contact of the redirect data-attribute.

Comment: if you're always redirecting to the same page then set that page as your redirect url. Should work.

Comment: The problem is that I don't know the url, as the same form is on many pages, and I want to return to the page the form is on but with an additional query string e.g. If the form is on example.com/page1 then I want to redirect to example.com/page1?status=thankyou. And if I am on example.com/page2 then I want to redirect to example.com/page2?status=thankyou

Comment: hmmm, I see, not sure if that's possible. Maybe check in with Ben at Sprout for a feature request?

Comment: OK Thanks a lot for your help, I will contact Sprout directly.